# SQL statement that will take 70 or so rows from multiple tables and pivot them to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

First Table is User_Nutrient_Amount (Multiple Column PK which are both FK: 2ndID maps to 2nd Table PK, ID1 maps to 3rd Table PK)

```
UserID|   NutID |   NutValue
 1    |    1    |     3.3
 1    |    2    |     9.8
 1    |    3    |     10.5
 .    |    .    |     ...
```

2nd Table is Nutrient (ID is PK)

```
NutID|   Name
 1   |    Sodium
 2   |    Potassium
 3   |    Fat
 .   |    .
```

3rd Table is Users (ID is PK)

```
UserID|   Name
 1    |    Joe
```

I would like to get the data such that

```
Sodium  | Potassium   | Fat     | .
3.3     | 9.8         | 10.5  | Value.
```

where the results all belong to on ID from the 3rd Table (result should be one row).

I've tried a few joins and managed to get the desired results, but then added another ID to the 3rd table and got back multiple rows (outer join).

**Edit (edited the data above):**

Here is my original query:

```
select ZN, CU, MN, SE, RT, BC, ATMG, [D-IU], VITC, THIA, RIBO, MG, PANT, B6, FOLA, B12, VITK, FOAC, CHOL, TRFA, TSAT, MUFA, PUFA, STAR, TOmega3, TOmega6, PROT, FAT, CARB, KCAL, TSUG, TDF, CA, FE, MG, P, K, NA from
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as PROT, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'PROT' and User_Amount.UserID = 1)  PROT left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as FAT, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'FAT')  FAT on FAT.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as CARB, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'CARB')  CARB on CARB.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as KCAL, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'KCAL')  KCAL on KCAL.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as TSUG, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'TSUG')  TSUG on TSUG.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as TDF, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'TDF')  TDF on TDF.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as CA, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'CA')  CA on CA.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as FE, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'FE')  FE on FE.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as MG, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'MG')  MG on MG.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as P, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'P')  P on P.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as K, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'K')  K on K.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as NA, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'NA')  NA on NA.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as ZN, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'ZN')  ZN on ZN.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as CU, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'CU')  CU on CU.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as MN, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'MN')  MN on MN.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as SE, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'SE')  SE on SE.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as [RT], User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'RT-æG')  [RT] on [RT].UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as [BC], User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'BC-æG')  [BC] on [BC].UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as ATMG, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'ATMG')  ATMG on ATMG.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as [D-IU], User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'D-IU')  [D-IU] on [D-IU].UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as VITC, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'VITC')  VITC on VITC.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as THIA, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'THIA')  THIA on THIA.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as RIBO, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'RIBO')  RIBO on RIBO.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as [N-MG], User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'N-MG')  [N-MG] on [N-MG].UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as PANT, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'PANT')  PANT on PANT.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as B6, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'B6')  B6 on B6.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as FOLA, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'FOLA')  FOLA on FOLA.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as B12, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'B12')  B12 on B12.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as VITK, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'VITK')  VITK on VITK.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as FOAC, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'FOAC')  FOAC on FOAC.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as CHOL, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'CHOL')  CHOL on CHOL.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as TRFA, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'TRFA')  TRFA on TRFA.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as TSAT, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'TSAT')  TSAT on NA.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as MUFA, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'MUFA')  MUFA on MUFA.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as PUFA, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'PUFA')  PUFA on PUFA.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as STAR, User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'STAR')  STAR on STAR.UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as [TOmega3], User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'TOmega n-3')  [TOmega3] on [TOmega3].UserID = PROT.UserID left outer join
    (select User_Amount.NutrientValue as [TOmega6], User_Amount.UserID
        from User_Amount inner join Nutrient on Nutrient.NutrientID = User_Amount.NutrientID
        where Nutrient.NutrientSymbol = 'TOmega n-6')  [TOmega6] on [TOmega6].UserID = PROT.UserID
```

Comment: Can you provide the queries that you tried? Also, more complete data (such as a ValueC) along with input and expected output would be very helpful.

Comment: What will the results of this query be used for? If it is going to be a report of some sort I would explore doing it with Excel pivot tables.

Comment: @ajdams I need all the Nutrient Values flattened for my application. The DB model is not mine so I can't change that.

Comment: Hmm... I made a small error and my original query does work. Until I find something better I will have to use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) query:

```
SELECT
  ZN, CU, MN, SE,
  [RT-æG] AS RT,
  [BC-æG] AS BC,
  ATMG, [D-IU], VITC,
  THIA, RIBO, MG,
  PANT, B6, FOLA,
  B12, VITK, FOAC,
  CHOL, TRFA, TSAT,
  MUFA, PUFA, STAR,
  TOmega3, TOmega6,
  PROT, FAT, CARB,
  KCAL, TSUG, TDF,
  CA, FE, P, K, NA
FROM (
  SELECT u.NutrientValue, n.NutrientSymbol
  FROM User_Amount u INNER JOIN Nutrient n ON n.NutrientID = u.NutrientID
  WHERE u.UserID = 1
) t
PIVOT (
  MAX(NutrientValue) FOR NutrientSymbol IN (
    ZN, CU, MN, SE,
    [RT-æG], [BC-æG],
    ATMG, [D-IU], VITC,
    THIA, RIBO, MG,
    PANT, B6, FOLA,
    B12, VITK, FOAC,
    CHOL, TRFA, TSAT,
    MUFA, PUFA, STAR,
    TOmega3, TOmega6,
    PROT, FAT, CARB,
    KCAL, TSUG, TDF,
    CA, FE, P, K, NA)
) x;
```

Basically, you need to list all possible (and necessary) Nutrient symbols both in the PIVOT clause and in the main SELECT clause.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. What's the difference between my query and this one as in does the pivot do what my query does, just with easier syntax? And what about performance?

Comment: Yes, I think this query should be equivalent to yours in terms of the results returned. As for performance, I wouldn't be able to pronounce any judgement confidently without being able to test both queries against some real data. Anyway, I wouldn't expect the PIVOT version to be *much* worse, if at all.